# I need a serial port program with logging timestamp

Tags: 19.04, serial-port, timestamp

I am using cutecom for serial port as it have a timestamp because i need to reference for two different data. But i can't log these datas with timestamp and need ms precise. Is there any suggestion?

Thanks,
Selim.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're after, but piping output from serial to something like `moreutils`'s `ts`:  `echo "my logged line" | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%.S]'` would give output: `[2019-11-06 13:07:36.774138] my logged line`

Comment: thank you @Smurfz87

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a terminal emulator, you can use `socat` with the `-v` option which logs all i/o with a timestamp. For example,

```
socat -v READLINE /dev/ttyS0,b19200,raw,echo=0 2>/tmp/log
```

Whatever you type on the stdin of this command will be sent to the serial port `ttyS0` at the given baud rate etc. And any input from the serial port will appear on stdout. In `/tmp/log` you will find lines like

```
> 2019/11/06 13:56:27.996129  length=6 from=0 to=5
hello
< 2019/11/06 13:56:37.024451  length=8 from=0 to=7
my reply
```

which corresponds to typing "hello\n" and getting "my reply" sent back.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

## Use ts!

On any Unix and in Windows Subsystem for Linux (aka. WSL) you can install the `moreutils` package which includes the `ts` tool. `ts` adds timestamps to text data that is fed to its standard input.

**Installation** on, e.g., Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install moreutils
```

**Usage**

Assuming that your serial port is, e.g., `ttyS70`, you can run this command line to

- read serial data from this port (using `cat`),
- add a timestamp (using `ts`), and
- print out the resulting line and at the same time save it to a file (using `tee`):

```
$ cat /dev/ttyS70 | ts | tee logfile
```

For my kind of serial data, the result looks like this:

```
Feb 14 18:37:03 13438 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
Feb 14 18:37:03 13440 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
Feb 14 18:37:04 13441 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
Feb 14 18:37:04 13442 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
Feb 14 18:37:04 13444 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
```

In this example, the serial port receives more than one line per second. As the timestamp resolution is seconds, several lines bear the same timestamp. To add a timestamp with higher resolution, `ts` allows you to control how the timestamp is formatted. For example `%.s` will give you seconds since 1970 in sub-second resolution:

```
$ cat /dev/ttyS70 | ts %.s | tee logfile
```

results in

```
1676396776.277146 18963 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
1676396776.405363 18964 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
1676396776.532999 18966 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
1676396776.660920 18967 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
1676396776.789261 18968 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
1676396776.917136 18969 1     0     0.0     19  -80.00    0.00 1
```

If you don't need absolute time data, use the switch `-s`. This will give you the time elapsed since start of the program:

```
$ cat /dev/ttyS70 | ts -s %.s | tee logfile
```

results in

```
0.072230 6459 42     0     0.0  20567 -100.00    0.00 1
0.199964 6459 42     0     0.0  20567 -100.00    0.00 1
0.311792 6460 42     0     0.0  20568 -100.00    0.00 1
0.439221 6460 42     0     0.0  20566 -100.00    0.00 1
0.567191 6460 42     0     0.0  20566 -100.00    0.00 1
0.694773 6460 42     0     0.0  20566 -100.00    0.00 1
0.822279 6461 42     0     0.0  20567 -100.00    0.00 1
0.950085 6461 42     0     0.0  20566 -100.00    0.00 1
1.061797 6461 42     0     0.0  20567 -100.00    0.00 1
1.189510 6461 42     0     0.0  20568 -100.00    0.00 1
```